# How to run google sample?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded a sample from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html) page. How can I run it in my android studio? Do I need to create a project or what?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a blank project using Android Studio or Eclipse with Android Bundle. After that you have to copy all java files from archive to your project in the src folder (keep the same structure), the resources (res folder) and replace the AndroidManifest.xml file with the one from archive.

Answer (score 0):

To import a project to Android Studio:

- Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
- From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project.
- Select the destination folder and click Next.
- Select the import options and click Finish.

for more info:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html